Pass a reference to python with pybind11
I have a class which holds an std::vector<int>. I have a method to get a reference to that vector.
class A {
public:
    std::vector<int> &v() {return m_v;}

private:
    std::vector<int> m_v;
};

    pybind11::class_<A>(m, "A")
        .def(pybind11::init<>())
        .def_property("v", &A::v);

Is there a way to pass the vector as a property to pybind11? I am trying def_property, but that doesn't work.

Can you provide an MWE and the error you get? Is it a compilation or runtime error?

It's a compilation error. I can share Godbolt code, but it's doesn't compile there because Python is not found. I'll update the question with the actual error I am getting
